# routing issue after bundling with webpack

Tags: angular, routes, webpack

I am bundling angular2 application. The routing is working very well in the dev-server mode. However, when I deploy the application onto Tomcat server using following webpack config, the routing does not working.
Even I can't access the page through direct url. For example, I wanted to access a certain page through http://localhost:8080/test/search (if you look at app.routing.ts, AppComponent maps to search and I put the generated .js files on the test directory in webapps)  but it shows HTTP Status 404. I only access search page through link in the welcome page. If somebody knows about this, please give some advice.

webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

webpack.prod.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {
    path: helpers.root('dist'),
    publicPath: './',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
  },

  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false // workaround for ng2
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
      mangle: {
        keep_fnames: true
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
      }
    })
  ]
});
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent },
    { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent },
    { path: 'search', component: AppComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

welcome.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'welcome-app',
    template: `
    <hr>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['login']" routerLinkActive="active">Sign In </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['search']" routerLinkActive="active">Search</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['logout']" routerLinkActive="active">Sign Out</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <hr>
    `
})

export class WelcomeComponent { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a webpack or a packing issue. It's a configuration issue in Tomcat (or any other web server).

Because /test/search is not an actual, existing page, you have to setup your web server to route any requests under your Angular app to the angular index page. This can be accomplished with the .htaccess file on Apache or URL rewrite module (on both Apache or IIS). It looks like Tomcat has a similar module. Check out their docs here: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought

In your package.json are your webpack and angular under 
dependencies
or
devdependencies

could explain it only working for Dev and not Prod

Comment: should be a comment.